# Joining two tables with one to many relatipnship in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, code-first

i have

```
  public class Menu
    {  
       public int ID { get; set;} 
       public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }



 public class Task
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }  
    }
```

i would like to know all tasks which has a certain List ID using LINQ queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var result = Menus.Where(menu => menu.ID == id)
                  .Select(menu => menu.Tasks)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Also you may want to peruse http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b as this would answer most of your queries like the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)

```
var list = Tasks.Where(l=>l.ID ==x);
```

or

```
   var list = from t in Tasks
              where t.ID == x
              select t;
```

***x*** will be the id you need to compare

Comment: Thanks alot,i meant to find the MenuID which in Tasks due to the one to many relation , not task id